# How to get ribbon to behave?

Tags: ms-access-2010, ribbon

I am a recent Access 2010 user from 2003 (don't judge me), but I have having a major problem with the ribbon not working as a reasonable person might expect.  I'm stuck having to constantly switch to the File tab to get the right options to enable or display which is extremely annoying.  What is the problem here?

(Sorry this is my first post and I do not have enough cred to embed pictures)

**Issue 1**

When I open a query in design mode, the ribbon opens with almost all the options disabled
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTyxD.png
Select, Make, Append, Update, Delete queries all look like this when I design them.  I have to click on the File tab, then back to Design to get the full breadth of options.

For macros, the Design tab shows those options but they are all disabled.  I have to switch to File and back to get them to enable.

**Issue 2**

If I click the grid to preview results, the ribbon does switch to show all the proper table view options.  This is good! It is what I would expect.

Unfortunately, when I go back into design view, the ribbon stays in the same configuration only it disables most of the table view options.  That makes since since I'm looking at the design and they don't apply, BUT it should be showing me design options instead.  Notice that the design tab doesn't even show up
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPx6a.png

Again, I have to click on File, then Home before it puts me back into the Design tab with the full breadth of options.

Edit:  Version: 14.0.7106.5001 (32-bit)

Comment: I don't see what you described.  My Access is from 32-bit Office 2010 with service pack 2.  Have you updated to SP2?

Comment: Thank you, I was so wrapped up in the ribbon behavior that I neglected to check basic things.  I was able to get it working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Access was already at SP2 version, but I did notice that windows update wanted a restart.  The log show 7 office & access updates installed.  The version number in access didn't change but now the ribbon behaves normally.  I had restarted previously so I believe the issue was resolved with the recent office updates and a restart.